# ¿Como impiar la consola despues de una ejecucion? | Java

Tags: java

[image: Limpiar Ejecución]

Mi pregunta es si existe una forma de ir limpiando la pantalla cuando pase a cierto punto para no tener mucha información en la pantalla y así sea mas fácil concentrarse por que el menú que aparece en la imagen lo tengo en loop así que esto ocupa mucho espacio.Gracias por leer buen día/noche/tarde.

Comment: Agrega tu codigo por favor, revisa [ask], saludos

Comment: Depende del sistema operativo.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución rápida podría ser agregar un `System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")`, no limpia la consola, pero podrias visualizar mejor el menú.

Si queres limpiarla literalmente podrías utilizar: 
`new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();`

Por tema de complejidad, yo solo agregaria los saltos de linea.

Ojala te sirva saludos